Problem in using scp with sshpass in Linux Shell
When I type the following command in Putty connected to Server A.
My file is copied from Server A to Server B.
sshpass -p 'myPass' scp userB@serverB_ip:/file.txt /home/XXXXXX.txt

However, it does not work when I write it in .sh file and executed by a crontab job.
My Shell file copyfilefromB.sh is as below:
#!/bin/sh
echo "start"
sshpass -p 'myPass' scp userB@serverB_ip:/file.txt /home/XXXXXX.txt
echo "end"

(I also tired the following, but also not work)
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'myPass' scp userB@serverB_ip:/file.txt /home/XXXXXX.txt
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'myPass' /usr/bin/scp userB@serverB_ip:/file.txt /home/XXXXXX.txt

My crontab file is as below:
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/copyfilefromB.sh >> copyfilefromB.log

In the log file, I can only read the word "start" and "end", no error is printed,
but the copy process is failed.
May I seek help from you guys? Anyone can help?
Thank you for your answering.

Add 2>&1 to the end of the crontab line so you'll get the error messages.

when you first time run ssh or scp on giving host they check ssh public key fingerprints
and ask would you like to accept and store them to ~/.ssh/known_hosts.
cron runs his tasks as root user, so perhapse there are not stored fingerprints at /root/.ssh/known_hosts, but it could not ask because does not have a terminal
add option -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new:
#!/bin/sh
echo "start"
sshpass -p 'myPass' scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new userB@serverB_ip:/file.txt /home/XXXXXX.txt
echo "end"


Thank you very much ! It works ! There should be a "space" between "-o StrictHostKeyChecking" . Full command is : sshpass -p 'myPass' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new userB@serverB_ip:/file.txt /home/XXXXXX.txt

Use this  :
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/copyfilefromB.sh >> copyfilefromB.log 2>&1

